# Terminology: What does "less than 1 and 0 integral" mean? (as in "functions with Lipschitz constant less than one and zero integral")

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, terminology, lipschitz-functions

I am working through *Applied Analysis* by John K. Hunter. Problem 2.7 states:

> Prove that the set of Lipschitz continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ with
> Lipschitz constant less than one and zero integral is compact in $C([0, 1])$.

What does "less than one and zero integral" mean? $|C|<1$? $0\leq C\leq 1$?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I interpret that to mean the constant is less than one, and also the integral of the function from zero to one is zero. There should be a comma there, that would help.

Comment: (+1) for comma. Alternatively, it could be written as "with zero integral and Lipschitz constant less than one", which removes the possibility that the conjunction (i.e. "and" operation) is part of the properties of the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: A comma there would sound rather unnatural to my ear. An extra "with" before "zero integral" would help, though.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen An extra comma in the sense of Oxford comma would be adequate only with three items listed. While confusing by the word sequence "one and zero", the only possible grammatical structure that I can parse into the given sentence is indeed as in this answer

Answer (score 7):

You are parsing the sentence improperly. The intended meaning is to consider the subset of $C([0,1])$ of $f$ such that $\mathrm{Lip}(f) \leq 1$ and $\int f = 0$. Note here we need $\leq 1$ not $< 1$, because clearly you could take $f(x) = -b/2 + b x$ (a line centered at $1/2$ with slope $b$) and send $b \to 1$.

Comment: "less than one" is dreadfully careless! It's like these applied mathematicians just don't care.